# How to GET the child record from parent child in ElasticSearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I simply would like to GET the child record directly after inserting both the Parent and the Child. Must I do a search query to just get the child or can I just do a standard GET with just the index, type, id of the child record?

thanks

Comment: I just searched another question that answered the above:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can just do a standard GET on the child `index`, `type` and `id`, but as *user983022* mentioned, you'll need to use the `parent_id` as the `routing` parameter in your request, otherwise ES will likely look on the wrong shard for the child document.

For more information on parent/child and routing, read http://www.elasticsearch.org/blog/customizing-your-document-routing/ and http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/get/ mentions using the `routing` parameter in `GET` requests.

Answer (score 1):

Answer: you need to add the routing parameter with the parent ID to retrieve the child record.